# check if UIButton is selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there any way to keep track the state of a UIButton whether it is selected or not? I tried accessing the selected property but it doesn't seem to work, seems to work only for UISwitch

Comment: what do you mean selected?  It doesnt make sense for a button...a button is either being pushed or existing normally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the state to selected if you want to use it like a toggle

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button;
{
    button.selected = ![button isSelected];
}
```

then you can just query it like normal

```
[self.button isSelected];
```

Comment: I wondered [self.button isSelected]; is not working in Xcode 7.2 even i created IBAction and it alway gives me <nil>.any help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes some UIButtons can have a selected state, which may only be momentary. However UIButtons inherit from UIControls which have a selected property. You can query to see if you button is selected using:

```
if([myButton isSelected])
    NSLog(@"Selected!")
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by “selected”? In standard usage, UIButtons only have three states: normal, disabled, and active, where “active” means “being tapped right now”. They’re not sticky.

Comment: It's just a helper boolean value for a button for your own programatic use that is avalable.  I use it if I have multiple alerts and I want to know which one was "selected".  You do have to control the boolean yourself though.